# Did I find $|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}|$ correctly?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Question: Suppose that $a \cdot b = 2$ 
and $$\cos\omega = 2/5.$$
Find $|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}|$

My work:
\begin{align*}
\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} & = |\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos\omega\\
2 & = |\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)\\
5 & = |\vec{a}||\vec{b}|
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}|& = |a||b|\sin\omega\\
|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}| & = 5 \sin\omega\\
|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}| & = 5\sqrt{19}
\end{align*}

Comment: I think it's $\sqrt{21}/5$, not $\sqrt{19}/5$.  Other than that, you should be good.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find the magnitude of the cross product given the dot product and the cosine of the angle between them, which is not that clear from your notation.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Whoops...$\sin \omega$ should be $\sqrt{21}/5$, not $\sqrt{19}/5$, so your answer will be $5 \sqrt {21}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your calculations, it appears that we are trying to find the magnitude of the cross-product of two vectors with dot product $2$ given that the cosine of the angle between them is $2/5$.

Let's denote the vectors by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, their dot product by $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$, and their cross product by $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}$.  We are given that $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 2$ and that $\cos\omega = 2/5$, where $\omega$ is the measure of the angle between the vectors. Let $\lVert \vec{v} \rVert$ be the magnitude of $\vec{v}$.
\begin{align*}
\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} & = 2\\
\lVert \vec{a} \rVert \lVert \vec{b} \rVert \cos\omega & = 2\\
\lVert \vec{a} \rVert \lVert \vec{b} \rVert \frac{2}{5} & = 2\\
\lVert \vec{a} \rVert \lVert \vec{b} \rVert & = 5
\end{align*}
By definition,
$$\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = \lVert \vec{a} \rVert \lVert \vec{b} \rVert \sin\omega$$
Since 
$$\cos^2\omega + \sin^2\omega = 1$$
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\sin^2\omega & = 1 - \cos^2\omega\\
             & = 1 - \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^2\\
             & = 1 - \frac{4}{25}\\
             & = \frac{21}{25}
\end{align*}
Taking square roots yields
$$|\sin\omega| = \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5}$$
Thus,
$$\lVert \vec{a} \times \vec{b} \rVert = \lVert \vec{a} \rVert \lVert \vec{b} \rVert |\sin\omega| = 5 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5} = \sqrt{21}$$